# Limiting CPU usage of 3rd library

Tags: c#, dll, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

In a project I use library that does some calculations on an image. Everything was fine, but since they released new version of the library, that is much better at the job (better results), it uses while calculating 100% CPU. The calculation takes about 55ms on average, and I don't really need it to be that fast.

Problem is the CPU usage, cause it makes a whole PC lagged and makes GUI really bad responding.

I figured out I could restrict the operation only to one CPU core. I just tested it with whole application via task manager and affinity settings and PC was just fine, while the calculations making results still really fast - 180ms.

Could it be correct solution? If so, how should I go about it:
Create another process, which would call the library and limit only this single process to one CPU core?
Or would it be possible to just limit one thread and its child threads?

Thank you.

Comment: As a first thing, I would try to run those calculations in a separate thread. But assigning CPU cores and limit the usage of a core is not directly controllable, C# language level is to high for that. Maybe also check the help forum/docs if that library you use.

Comment: If you can mess with the threads on that level I would instead look into changing the priority. Using 100% cpu is what you want, as long as the cpu is not required for higher priority operations.

Comment: I wrote mail to the author of the library. He told me there is no way to limit the CPU usage and the calculation is already multi-threaded.

Comment: I will look into thread priorities. Thanks

Comment: You need the cooperation of the code constructing the threads and/or running on the threads to do this from your application, you might need to send the author another email.

Comment: What about creating separated process with lower priority for just using the library?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that the gui hangs. The correct way of handling that is usually to have long operations running in a separate thread and update the result asynchronously. This way the gui will stay responsive while another core computes things

Comment: I'am calling the operation from separated thread and invoking results back to the GUI. But the operation is being sometimes called more often and the 100% CPU usage really makes the PC less usable.